# Why doesn't XAMPP write the path to css?

Tags: html, css, xampp

Why doesn't XAMPP write the path to css?

Path: htdocs/my_project/index.html - this is my file
Path: htdocs/my_project/css/demo.css - this is my file of style

**This does not work:**

```
<link rel=“stylesheet” href=”css/demo.css” type=“text/css”>
```

If I transfer my css file in main directory (htdocs/my_project) and change link to css file to:

```
<link rel=“stylesheet” href=”demo.css” type=“text/css”>
```

then it does work.

Comment: is the Apache service running? .. and are you viewing your site in the browser as `http://localhost/my_project/` ?

Comment: yes. Apache service. You right!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this to see if Xampp will go back one directory

```
<link rel=“stylesheet” href=”/css/demo.css” type=“text/css”>
```

OR

```
<link rel=“stylesheet” href=”../css/demo.css” type=“text/css”>
```

Comment: First of all thanks for this. can you please tell me what is the reason of this?